# Centering a fixed width div flanked by two variable divs

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to set up a display that has an icon centered in a div.  To the left and/or right is a variable amount of text.  Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-text">This text is on the left</div>
    <div class="icon-cell"><div class="icon smiley-face"></div></div>
    <div class="right-text">And more text is over here...</div>
</div>
```

My goal would be for icon-cell to always be centered horizontally, presuming `.container` has a `width` of 100%.

I was using a table for a little while, but it wasn't possible to do:

```
<td style="width:50%"></td>
<td style="width:48px"></td>
<td style="width:50%"></td>
```

Any ideas on how to do this without using Javascript?

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/yqurG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `display: inline-block` for the divs in conjunction with `text-align: center`:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
}

.container > div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container > .icon-cell {
    width: 50px;
}
```

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RYaDX/)**</kbd>

There will occur problems, when you insert more text. Then you need to fix the width of your container-elements and eliminiate white-space between inline-blocks (I use `font-size: 0`). Here's another example:

<kbd>**[More Text](http://jsfiddle.net/RYaDX/6/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is close!  The problem is that large amounts of text move the center icon.  See http://jsfiddle.net/RYaDX/2/

Comment: See my second fiddle. I used percentual widths for the container. I hope this will work in your case. If not, I'd tend to position the icon absolute and use padding on the text-containers

Comment: I edited my fiddle again with the `position: absolute` method. This will suffice your needs, I believe.

Comment: Cool - looks like we basically came up with the same answer.  :)  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a clean **newspaper** kind of look.....

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.left-text {
  position:absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .2);
  margin-left:0px;
  top:0px;
  padding-right:350px;
  text-align:justify;
  text-justify:auto;
}
.right-text {
  position:absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
  margin-right:0px;
  top:0px;
  padding-left:350px;
  text-align:justify;
  text-justify:auto;
}
.icon.smiley-face {
  background: url(//placehold.it/48/48/00ff00);
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this trick may work

```
.icon{
  width:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css float and align.
CSS:
    .left-text { float: left; }
    .right-text { float: right; }
    .icon-cell { text-align: center; }
    .container { display: inline-block; }

Answer (score 0):

You can just use margins and display: inline-block; in css

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I'm a bit late to the party, but this can also be done using `display: table-cell;`. Large amounts of texts should wrap rather than push the icon around and if you want padding for the "cells" you won't need to compensate for the width of the centered icon.

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  display: table-row;
}

.container > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
}

.container > .icon-cell {
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.container > .icon-cell img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljho1nx9/2/